# look for C# multithread application with plugin architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, plugins, multithreading

I'm looking for an example of multithread C# application who use plug'in architecture, can any one help me please ?
many thanks

Comment: perhaps you should take a look at MEF?

Answer (score 1):

hey, it seems you need a c# project and not an IDE, don't you?

I can give you some tips about multithreading and plugins, don't have an example at hand, though.

About multithreading: you can use System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker class for asynchronous threading, or you can use create your own BackgroundWorker class (with Thread.Start(ThreadStart or ParameterizedThreadStart)).

For plugins, i recommend you implement a common structure for a plugin folder/configuration, then realization would be a joke.

e.g.
/plugins folder:
/plugins/pluginname/conf.xml
/plugins/pluginname/bin/
/plugins/pluginname/bin/pluginname.dll

Comment: -1... nice advice, but you should not ignore System.ComponentModel.Composition which hsa the coplete infrastructure already ;)

Comment: System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker is a shorthand when you just want to call a method with callback.

your choice, but, for your information, i've written production code with that model and achieved great performance. so, that model works :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sharp develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)

Comment: many thanks, MEF seems good, I'll see sharp develop also when I have time